# How to reshape dataset as input for RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i try to feed my model with dataset values but i get a shape error. Can somebody help with it and explain how it works with datasets? Many thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
"mydata/*.csv",
batch_size=64,
field_delim=",",
num_epochs=1,
select_columns=['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'Y'],
label_name='Y',
shuffle=False,
prefetch_buffer_size=64)

dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.concat(
[tf.expand_dims(x['X1'], axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(x['X2'], axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(x['X3'], axis=-1)], axis=-1), y))

inputs = Input(shape=(None, 3))
hidden1 = SimpleRNN(3, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, 1))(inputs)
outputs = Dense(units=1, activation='linear')(hidden1)  # hidden layer 1

model_rnn = Model(hidden1, outputs)
model_rnn.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer="adam", metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
history = model_rnn.fit(dataset, epochs=2, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: As far as I was aware you don't need to specify the batch dimension in the Input layer? Try Input(shape=(3,))

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I get input dimension errors. I changed the settings to 

inputs = Input(shape=(3, None)) # 3 Features/Colums
hidden1 = SimpleRNN(3, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,))(inputs)

and get the following error:

    "ValueError: Input 0 of layer simple_rnn is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 5)"

Comment: What are you trying to do with the CSV? Can you add more details on what your sample data looks like and how you want to feed that data to the RNN? The input to an RNN needs to have 3 dimensions i.e. batch dimension, time dimension, feature dimension.